# How can I resize a polygon on google map using flutter?

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart

I'm using google_maps_flutter package to use google maps and add a polygon.I want to resize/adjust the polygon to get the correct area.

I tried searching for any property to adjust, but did not find one.

This is the code where I'm adding the polygon to google maps.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return MaterialApp(
   home: Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
       title: Text('Maps Sample App'),
       backgroundColor: Colors.green[700],
       actions: <Widget>[
         IconButton(
             icon: Icon(Icons.call_made),
             tooltip: 'Sign Out',
             onPressed: _signOut),
       ],
     ),
     body: Container(
       height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
       width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
       child: GoogleMap(
           onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
           initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
             target: LatLng(widget.location.first.latitude,
                 widget.location.first.longitude),
             zoom: 11.0,
           ),
                 polygons: Set<Polygon>.of(<Polygon>[
             Polygon(
               polygonId: PolygonId('area'),
       points: _points,
       geodesic: true,
       strokeColor: Colors.blue,
       fillColor: Colors.lightBlue.withOpacity(0.1),
       visible: true
             )
           ]),
           markers: Set<Marker>.of(<Marker>[
             Marker(
                 markerId: MarkerId('1'),
                 position: LatLng(widget.location.first.latitude,
                     widget.location.first.longitude),
                 visible: true,
                 draggable: true)
           ])),
     ),
   ),
 );
}
```

How can I resize the polygon by dragging the vertices?

Comment: In the JS API it is done by setting the Polygon option `editable: true` but that doesn't seem to be supported in the [flutter library](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter/latest/google_maps_flutter/Polygon-class.html).

Comment: Yes I checked that. So, Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the polygon is immutable. You have to create a new Polygon and add it to the Polygon set.

I did that using Markers with onDragEnd. That function receives the new position of the marker. I use the marker positions to create the positions of the polygon.

You can check place_marker.dat in the [example directory](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter/example/lib) of google_maps_flutter to  see how you can dynamically place markers. In my case, I'm using GoogleMap's onLongPress, instead of a button, to add a marker.